# Craps game doesnt return right values

Tags: c, function

wiHi everyone since last time i found extreme help on here, im gonna ask a question again

My code doesnt return right values :
something is wrong in the play_game function and i cant figure out what it is.I believe that all cases are covered but somehow they end up messed up.
also the code doesnt loop for everytime i want to play a game after the second game it stops.
**this is not an assignment**

any suggestion?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int sum, point, win = 0, roll = 0;    
bool play_game(void);
int roll_dice(void);

int main(void){

srand(time(NULL)); 


play_game();

char input[10];

do{ point = 0;
    play_game();
    if(win == 1){ // I'm assuming that play returns whether you won or not
        printf("You won!\n");
    }else{
        printf("You lost!\n");
    }
    printf("Would you like to continue? y/n\n");
    gets(input);
}while(*input == 'y'); // gets() flushes the buffer for next time you need input
return 0;
}


bool play_game(void){

point=0;
roll_dice();
printf("Your point is %d\n", sum);

while(roll == 1) /* first round */
{
  if(sum == 7 || sum == 11)
     return win = 1;
  else if(sum == 2 || sum == 3 || sum == 12)
     return win = 0;
  else if(sum == 1 || sum == 4 || sum == 5 || sum == 6 || sum == 8 || sum == 9 || sum    == 10){
     point=sum;
     roll_dice();
     }

}

while(roll > 1) /* all others rounds*/
{  
      if(sum == 7)
        return win = 0;
      else if(sum == point)
        return win = 1;
      else if(sum != point || sum != 7)
      roll_dice();

} 

}

int roll_dice(void){

int a,b;

a=1+rand() % (6);
b=1+rand() % (6);
sum=a+b;
roll++;
printf("You rolled %d\n", sum);
return sum;

}
```

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND5KC.png)

Comment: I have never played a game of craps where the dice always returned the right value... :(

Comment: @James McNellis: Did you want to borrow my dice? :)

Comment: tbh i didnt even know this game existed until i tried to make this code for an exercise :)

Comment: @kdma what values are you getting that are wrong?  What values are you expecting?

Comment: see http://i.imgur.com/ND5KC.png
i always win even if the point is different than the sum returned from roll_dice :/

Comment: It's more conventional to declare functions outside of `main()` or any other function. So in this case, the first non-blank line of `main()` and the third non-blank line of play_game() should just be cut and pasted back before `main()`.

Comment: ok this was my bad i forgot to put primitives at top :) thanks for input

Comment: The code here is so wrong, i fear correcting it would pretty much mean a rewrite.  `play_game` should have a `while` loop in it, as should `main` (but not where they currently are); the `while` loops that exist already should be `if`/`else` statements; the `getchar` should be moved outside of any conditional statements so that it runs exactly once per iteration, and the dice will never add up to more than 10 because of how `rand()` is being used.  Add in the style issues (function declarations within functions, globals that don't need to be, etc), and that covers just about every line of code.

Comment: @cHao:  Given a die has 6 sides, numbered 1 through 6 and two dice, the range of values are 2 through 12, inclusive.  Let one die have a 6 showing.  If the second die shows 5 or 6, the sum of the dice will "add up to more than 10".  I could be wrong though.

Comment: @Thomas:  That's kinda my point.  Real dice can have a 6 showing.  The dice defined by this program can't, cause the value will always be 1 + (some value from 0 to 4).

Comment: @cHao
thanks for your input,i am very new to programming so all criticism is accepted :)
I will rewrite the code with all the suggestion from this post

Comment: @Thomas You seem to have badly misread. cHao said that the dice (as programmed in the so wrong code) will never add up to more than 10, not that dice can never add up to more than 10.

Comment: @cHao
I used global var so i could understand better what whats going on between functions and for the other errors i am fixing them

Comment: @kdma: It's not quite *as* evil in a tiny program like this...but it's still evil in general.  In my experience, global variables tend to make interactions between functions *more* complicated, rather than less, since a global can be changed anywhere by any piece of code.

Comment: @kdma I urge you to take a programming class or work your way through a tutorial, because you are making a great number of basic errors that indicate that you're in over your head.

Comment: I already take a programming class thats why i am here,to learn.
I know that i am making errors,i wont stop until i make this little baby work :)

Comment: @kdma Again, you are **in over your head** -- you need more instruction before you can get this thing to work. And please please please do not edit code that you have posted in a question -- it obsoletes all the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop needs to be more like:

```
main(){
    char input[10];

    do{
        score = 0; //Always initialize the score
        if(play_game()){ // I'm assuming that play returns whether you won or not
            printf("You won!\n");
        }else{
            printf("You lost!\n");
        }
        printf("Would you like to continue? y/n\n");
        gets_s(input, 9);
    }while(*input == 'y'); // gets() flushes the buffer for next time you need input
}
```

Comment: never used *gets i believe is a pointer to a function and i havent started using them yet so dont know how to implement it :)

Comment: Basically, it returns an entire line of input and strips the '\n' at the end. The * before it means 'the first character of the following string'.

Comment: You can also use `if(gets()[0] == 'y'){`

Comment: trying to implement it but i get compiling errors that im unable to resolve, i bet this solution is brilliant but my skill are way lower :)

Comment: a simple but criptic :gets cannot be used as function

Comment: my bad the error is
242 C:\Dev-Cpp\include\stdio.h too few arguments to function `char* gets(char*)'

Comment: Okay, I forgot about that. Try the new version.

Comment: 23 C:\Users\Franco\Desktop\c files\dadi.cpp `gets_s' undeclared (first use this function) 
At global scope: 
27 C:\Users\Franco\Desktop\c files\dadi.cpp expected unqualified-id before "return" 
27 C:\Users\Franco\Desktop\c files\dadi.cpp expected `,' or `;' before "return" 
28 C:\Users\Franco\Desktop\c files\dadi.cpp expected declaration before '}' token

Comment: Oh. Sorry, just use `gets(input)` then. `gets_s(char *, int)` is only in the .NET library.

Comment: ok fixed it :) gonna start studying pointer from now on thanks for help man

Comment: No problem. Though, if you really wanted to show your appreciation, you could accept my answer. Haha.

Comment: I am also new to the site so i didnt know i could "accept" answers :)
did it for everyone that helped!

Answer (score 3):

A couple of points:

- You probably want `1 + rand() % 6`
- The return value of `printf()` is probably not what you want to return from `roll_dice()`

Comment: fixed the sum but i dont understand why the value from printf shouldnt be the right one

Comment: @kdma: because printf returns the number of characters printed, which isn't what you want (sum).

Comment: @kdma:  Because the return value of `printf()` is the number of characters printed out.  That has nothing to do with the dice roll, except that if it's 10, 11, or 12 there will be one more character than if it were smaller.

Comment: @forsvarir
@David Thornley

i am obviously missing something here could you explain it?
i think the function looks right

Comment: @kdma -- the return and printf should be on different lines -- you want to "return sum".

Comment: I've attempted to edit the answer, but it's pending peer review =)

Comment: @kdma People are giving you good answers which you seem not to be reading, both here and when you were told that you are rolling 5-sided dice but you came back and said the formula is right when it obviously isn't. Here, `return printf`... couldn't possibly be what you want.

Comment: @Jim Balter
i read them and i fixed those but there is still something wrong gonna update the code in topic start now

Comment: @kdma "gonna update the code" **Do not** do that ever at SO ... it obsoletes the answers. If you want to post new code, do it in a separate question, or add it as a separate section of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Kyle's answer is just fine (as I see it), But I can spot a few problems, hope it'll help you in further cases.

- You always win, and I know it's nice, but I bet it's not the expected behavior:

---

```
while(true) // This will always happen, because true is always evaluated as true
 {
  printf("Won\n\n");
  printf("Play again? y/n: ");
  break;
  }  

while(false) //This will never happen, since false is always evaluated as false
 {
  printf("Lost\n\n");
  printf("Play again? y/n: ");
  break;
  }
```

I think you meant to check the result of `play_game()`. So add another variable and check against it:

```
bool win;
win = play_game();
while (win == true)
...
while (win == false)
...
```

---

- Why using while loop there? you break it in the first iteration anyway

---

```
if(win == true)
{
  printf("Won\n\n");
}  
else
{
  printf("Lost\n\n");
}
printf("Play again? y/n: ");
```

---

- The game will run not more than twice, because you don't have a loop that depends on the answer, but only an if statement that is evaluated just one time:

---

```
if(v=getchar() == 'y') //This is the second time the code runs, after that? nada.
 {
  point =0; /* reset point var */
  play_game();
  }
 else if(v=getchar() == 'n') // Why adding this check? you're going out anyway after the if-else
  exit(1);
```

---

**EDIT**

When you use a while loop, what you do is saying:
While (some expression in the parenthesis) is true, execute the code in the block {..} and then check again the expression in parenthesis.

If you write `while(true)`, you actually writing `while true is true, execute the code in the block`. And this will always happen.
If you write `while(false)` you actually write `while false is true, execute the code in the block`. and this false is never true, than it will never execute the code in the block.
If you want a real condition here, you can use `while(play_game())`. this is like writing, `while the returned value from the function play_game is true, execute the code in the block` and then the code will be executed only when the play_game function return true (which indicates a win in the game).

There are many good C tutorials out there, start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345506/where-is-the-best-place-to-learn-c) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books)

Comment: `if/while (win == true)` can -- and should! -- be shortened to just `if/while (win)`.  Likewise with `win == false` and `!win`.  Mainly a style issue, but still.

Comment: `while(true) // This will always happen, because true is always evaluated as true
 {
  printf("Won\n\n");
  printf("Play again? y/n: ");
  break;
  } `

I thought that the fuction returned true when i rolled the same value as the point and false when i rolled 7, i am new to functions so i have much to learn :)
And yes i tried to check the result of this function as win/lose but i dont seem to understand your suggestion about using another var.
thanks for help :)

Comment: @kdma - the function returns a boolean variable indeed, but if you don't assign it to anything or evaluates it immediately (as Kyle did), then you 'loses' it. in your `while` you shouldn't check `while(true)` because true is true, you should check if a specific value is true (in this case it is the return value from your function)

Comment: @cHao - earlier I misunderstand you, and my comment was not related to yours. Yes, it should be shortened, but it's much clearer for a new-comer to understand when you compare it to true/false.

Comment: @kdma It has nothing to do with functions or what they return. Every time someone answers you, you backtalk instead of reading what they wrote.

Comment: `if(v=getchar() == 'y')` is horrible code. Is `v` supposed to contain the char, or the value of the test? We can't even tell here because `v` is never used, but since it's declared `char` it's probably supposed to receive the char, which of course it doesn't.

Comment: @Jim - I thought a better approach is to go step-by-step. You can't just drop ANYTHING right away on OP. I tried to focus on the important issues as I saw it (which are the flow control issues)

Comment: @Jim im just trying to explain what i was trying to do to learn better i dont have any interest on backtalking about a craps program.
Anyway the error was that i knew that in C bool dont exists and those values are 0 and 1 so i thought that using true as 1 and false as 0 as function result and returning them was a good idea :)

Comment: Focusing on the control flow is good, since the OP is so completely confused about it, but if you quote buggy code you should still point out the bugs in it. If that v=getchar... isn't corrected here, the OP will continue using it and will be baffled by the result.

Comment: @kdma "Anyway the error was ..." Again the backtalk. No, that's NOT what the error was ... the error was that you completely and utterly misunderstand the structure of C programs. See MByD's edit section and please stop thinking that you have ANY idea what is right or wrong yourself.

Comment: Tell me if i am wrong:
When i check through the IF i also assign to V the result from the function getchar(), if it is a y i loop again else i quit
i believe its bad styling but i want first a working prototype and then i will make it look pretty :)

Comment: @kdma - you are wrong about that, `if` is not a loop. Let's cut the talkbacks here, please read a book from the listed books in the links I posted, I wish I could, but I can't explain all C basics in comments (probably I can't explain them all anyway :) )

Comment: @kdma You are wrong: `v=getchar() == 'y'` is parsed as `v=(getchar() == 'y')` ... the value of `v` is `1` if the char was a 'y' and 0 if it wasn't.

Comment: i already own the K&R C book, will look into function section more this was a test for me with tremendous results as you can see :)(this an exercise from function section)

Comment: @kdma "the error was that i knew that in C bool dont exists" -- That doesn't make any sense. `bool` does exist in C as of C99, and you used `bool` declarations and bool constants `true` and `false`. Those were not in error and had nothing to do with the errors being discussed. and now you have rewritten the code in your question making these answers and comments obsolete. **Please don't do that** (modify code in your question).

Comment: @kdma "tremendous results as you can see" No, what I see is that you are cutting and pasting responses but it's not at all clear that you understand them and won't make the same mistakes the next time.

Comment: I understood all of them except for the one that made me use pointers on the do-while loop in main();
I thought that editing after answers was a good policy so others could look at working code after the fixing, i repeat i am new here i dont know what im supposed to do and i am also trying to keep up with the fast paced answers here!every help is apprecciated

Comment: @Jim you are obviously more prepared than me on the subject, when you thought i was backtalking i was merely explaining what i had in my mind so i could make it work the next time.also i passed the whole day on this piece of code so my mind is becoming tired and im making more errors but you know when you want fix something att all costs even if you are tired?:)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell from your description (please say what you expected to happen, and what happened instead), but the first thing I notice is that you are rolling 5-sided dice for `a` and `b`.

Comment: It is hard to tell from your description (please say what you expected to happen, and what happened instead), but the first thing I notice is that you are rolling 5-sided dice for `a` and `b`.

does the pic at the end help?
example
the point in that pic is 4 it should get confronted with the result from roll_dice() on each roll and as you can see i won with a 10 instead of a 4
the dice is right that formula should always receive a and b > 0 (i think)

Comment: @kdma If you want help, please read what people say. Your formula is *clearly* wrong and *clearly* rolls 5-sided dice, and it's misleadingly formatted. The correct formula is `a = (rand() % 6) + 1;` which yields numbers in the range 1 ... 6.

Answer (score 0):

Rolling of the dice is happening at at incorrect points during your game sequence.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// add defines to make states easier to read
#define WIN 1
#define LOSE 0

static int sum, point, win = 0, roll = 0;    
//bool play_game(void); 
int play_game(void); // changed return type to be int
int roll_dice(void);

int main(void){

    srand(time(NULL)); 


    // play_game(); // unncessary

    char input[10];

    do
    {
        point = 0;
        //play_game();
        // if(win == 1){
        if(play_game()){ // use return value from play_game()
            printf("You won!\n");
        }else{
            printf("You lost!\n");
        }
        printf("Would you like to continue? y/n\n");
        // gets(input);
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin); // a safer input read
    } while(*input == 'y'); // gets() flushes the buffer for next time you need input
    return 0;
}


// bool play_game(void)
int play_game(void) // changed return type to be int
{

    point=0;
    // remove as this messes up the roll sequence.
    // roll_dice();
    // incorrect place to display this message
    //printf("Your point is %d\n", sum);

    // the while loop here is unnecessary
    //while(roll == 1) /* first round */
    //{
        roll_dice(); // add for initial come out roll.
        if(sum == 7 || sum == 11) { // I use braces to remove ambiguity
            // return win = 1;
            return WIN;
        } else if(sum == 2 || sum == 3 || sum == 12) {
            //return win = 0;
            return LOSE;
        }
        // sum will never be 1
        // on that note if it control reaches here it will be one of the other numbers.
        //} else if(sum == 1 || sum == 4 || sum == 5 || sum == 6 || sum == 8 || sum == 9 || sum == 10){
        // point=sum;
        // roll_dice(); // remove as this messes up the roll sequence.
        // }
        point=sum;
        printf("Your point is %d\n", sum);

    //}

    // while(roll > 1) /* all others rounds*/
    while (1) // might as well loop forever 
    {  
        roll_dice(); // add for subsequent dice rolls
        if(sum == 7) {
            //return win = 0;
            return LOSE;
        } else if(sum == point) {
            // return win = 1;
            return WIN;
        }
        // remove as this is unnecessary
        //  else if(sum != point || sum != 7)
        // remove as this messes up the roll sequence.
          //roll_dice();

    } 

}

int roll_dice(void){

    int a,b;

    a=1+rand() % (6);
    b=1+rand() % (6);
    sum=a+b;
    // roll++; // unncessary
    printf("You rolled %d\n", sum);
    return sum;

}
```